# Issue in getting the converted image in image magick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I wanted to convert all my images to jpg format and save in the same folder where I am storing other images while uploading them. So had added the following code.

```
folder_path = "/#{@project.project_code}/prj#{self.attachment_folder}"
self.attachment_folder = folder_path
newfile = attachment_file_name[/[^.]+/]+ ".jpg"
```

Then using `system('convert #{folder_path}/#{self.attachment_file_name} #{folder_path}/#{newfile}')` wanted to convert and save it in the same folder... But I am not getting any error in my logs nor is the converted file being seen in my appropriate folder. But I am getting the following in my logs

```
By default, the image format of `file' is determined by its magic
number.  To specify a particular image format, precede the filename
with an image format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the
image type as the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps).  Specify 'file' as
'-' for standard input or output.
```

How will I be able to see my converted file also in the same folder?

My code is as:

```
if attachable_type.downcase == "project"
  @project = Project.select("projects.project_code").not_deleted.find_by_id(self.attachable_id) if !self.attachable_id.blank?
  if !@project.blank?
   user_nick_name = self.current_user_nick_name.downcase if !self.current_user_nick_name.blank?
   self.attachment_file_name.gsub!(/\.|_#{@user_id}\./,"_#{@user_id}.")
   file_name = (@project.project_code+"_"+user_nick_name+"_"+self.attachment_file_name).downcase if !user_nick_name.blank?
   #self.attachment_folder = "#{@project.project_code}/references/"
    folder_path = "/#{@project.project_code}/prj#{self.attachment_folder}"
    self.attachment_folder = folder_path
    newfile = attachment_file_name[/[^.]+/]+ ".jpg"
    puts "#{folder_path}/#{self.attachment_file_name}"
    puts "#{folder_path}/#{newfile}"
    puts "#{newfile}"
    # thumb = Magick::Image.read("#{folder_path}#{self.attachment_file_name}").first
    system('convert #{folder_path}/#{self.attachment_file_name} #{folder_path}/#{newfile}')
  end
end
```

Output is as:

```
/bts/prj/references/animatic/RefineryCMS_284.png
/bts/prj/references/animatic/RefineryCMS_284.jpg
RefineryCMS_284.jpg
```

Comment: The error means that the filename you are supplying for the output file doesn't end in `.jpg` or any recognisable image format extension. Try outputting the filename to debug.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am able to see my file name in logs. 

 Output for #{folder_path}/#{self.attachment_file_name}->   
    /bts/prj/references/animatic/RefineryCMS_284.png  
 Output for #{folder_path}/#{newfile} -> 

/bts/prj/references/animatic/RefineryCMS_284.jpg

Comment: And what is it? How about writing the command you send to `system()` to the logs and showing that? Click `edit` underneath your question and paste the output into your question please - it's easier to read than comments.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Have added my code snippet in the link above

Comment: I don't *speak* Ruby, but shouldn't you pass the string to `system()` in double quotes so that the variables are expanded, rather than in single quotes?

Comment: But the same code is working if I hard code some image path with single quotes only

Comment: Try it! If you hard code the image path, you are not needing to get variables expanded, which is exactly the problem. At the moment you are telling ImageMagick to write to a file that ends in `#{newfile}` and it doesn't know what type of file that it - because it doesn't end in `.jpg`

Comment: But the output of #{newfile} is the image with jpg extension only.. like RefineryCMS_284.jpg

Comment: After adding double quotes its giving me the error: convert: unable to open image `/bts/prj/references/animatic/RefineryCMS_284.png': No such file or directory

Comment: Good! We are getting closer - at least ImageMagick is now looking for something like the correct file instead of looking for the name of your variables. Is there a file in your filesystem by that name? And is it accessible to the user running your Ruby?

Comment: Try `ls -l /bts/prj/references/animatic/RefineryCMS_284.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your help and time. The issue is resolved by adding #{Rails.root}/public before the folder_path